# Parsing result for nested value from api response

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, xml, parsing

Hi I get a payload from soap api as result.
 from result I did following

```
console.log(util.inspect(result, false, null));
```

I get following result

```
{ 'S:Envelope': 
             { '$' : { 'xmlns:s : 'http://.....'},
             'S:Body':
               { 'n:sendresponse':
                 { '$': {'xmlns:ns2': 'http://......'},
                   tranResult:{id: '', temp: '224'}}}}
```

What I want to do is parse value of temp. I am doing something like this

```
var resl=util.inspect(result, false, null);
```

I dont know how to proceed with it. Please let me know how I can get value of temp from the result and assign it to var temperature
Thanks

Comment: You can use bracket notation  like `var temperature = resl['S:Envelope']['$']['S:Body']['$']['tranResult]['temp']`. (May be variables are different in your actual case)

Comment: @J We certainly do not have much info in your case. My answer is just a guess for your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is a first class citizen in JavaScript and you can traverse its structure easily like a tree. In the given example, you want to traverse further down until you get to `temp`. You can go from the root node (the object itself) to the child element by calling the child element name either directly using dot notation (e.g., `parent.child`) or using brackets if it has special characters or if the child name is stored in another variable (e.g., `parent['child']`).

For the given example, the path to `temp` is `o['S:Envelope']['S:Body']['n:sendresponse']['tranResult']['temp']`.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a json object, you first have to parse it to get an object which will make it easier to access the member `temp` and retrieve its value.

How to work with object in JS. Check [working with object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Parsing json, you can use either `JSON.parse(jsonString)` or `jsonString.toJSON()` (if you can in your case) to get the object.

Comment: `JSON.parse()` takes a `string` as an argument, the `result` in the question is already an object,

Comment: @Taki I just provided what J can do with what have in hand and specifically using `jsonString` to distinguish `string` from `object`. I think J will understand what can be done. As long as the object is retrieved with > How to work with object in JS. Check working with object.